# How to dynamically align text using transform.position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to dynamically align horizontal text in the unity canvas though i cannot seem to perfect this.  The edge of the text should be aligned to the right of the screen using: screen.width - text.rect.width/2+5(5 for padding) i am also using the content size fitter to scale the horizonal transform to set the correct transform width of the text.  The issue im having is it starts of as aligned though the more text added the more the spacing between the edge of the text.transform and the edge of the right hand side of the screen. it doesnt stay static...  Using anchor points wont work as i will be aligning image and button to the left of this text.

Comment: so what man! you can use anchor for text and use that text as reference/anchor for your image and button

Comment: so what hamza! the text transform rect would expand beyond the edge of the screen. moving the pivot point solved this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using transform.position to align to the right of the screen does not align text properly  as the text increases.  To solve this i created a panel attached a horizontal layout group with a content size fitter and attached the ui text as children. Then select the parent panel and move the pivot point to the very right of its transform.rect.  This way the text expands dynamically to the left and not out of view while keeping an exact margin from the edge of the screen.
Still not sure why the manual way of using the panel's transform.position relative to the edge of the screen doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a HorizontalLayoutGroup component so that it does it automatically. You need to make the group size equal to the amount of items so that the don't get shrunk to fit.